# Wrapper class for dispatching to multiple similar instances without code repetition

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, interface, dispatch

I have multiple implementations of a base class (or interface; in the following `Logger`) which can be used interchangeably. Each implementation handles the various events in a different way and the user can specify what type of logger they want to use (`LoggerA` or `LoggerB`):

```py
class Logger:
    def log_foo(self, a):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def log_bar(self, b, c):
        raise NotImplementedError


class LoggerA(Logger):
    def log_foo(self, a):
        print(a)

    def log_bar(self, b, c):
        pass  # Don't log this event.


class LoggerB(Logger):
    def log_foo(self, a):
        self._send_to_api(a)

    def log_bar(self, b, c):
        self._send_to_api((b, c))

    def _send_to_api(self, data):
        pass
```

In addition there should be the option to use multiple logger instances at once, with the same interface as if it were a single logger instance. So it will be used in the following way:

```py
logger: Logger = create_logger_from_config()
logger.log_foo(...)
```

So I'm about to create this drop-in replacement for multiple loggers and I find myself repeating a lot of code in the following way:

```py
class MultiLogger(Logger):
    def __init__(self, loggers: list[Logger]):
        self.loggers = loggers

    def log_foo(self, a):
        for logger in self.loggers:
            logger.log_foo(a)

    def log_bar(self, b, c):
        for logger in self.loggers:
            logger.log_bar(b, c)
```

This example contains only two methods but in reality there's a plenitude of methods which repeat this pattern. I'm trying to come up with a solution that avoids this repetition and which is compatible with type checking following [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/). What would be a good option to achieve this?

---

I thought about dynamically dispatching via `__getattribute__` but that seems very cumbersome:

```py
class MultiLogger(Logger):
    def __init__(self, loggers: list[Logger]):
        self.loggers = loggers

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        obj = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if callable(obj):
            def proxy(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    return obj(*args, **kwargs)
                except NotImplementedError:
                    for logger in self.loggers:
                        getattr(logger, name)(*args, **kwargs)
            return proxy
        return obj
```

I also thought about making `Logger` a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) and then dispatch in `__getattr__`. While that [works for mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/520) it is not specified in [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) and for example PyCharm flags it as a type mismatch:

```py
from typing import Protocol


class Logger(Protocol):
    def log_foo(self, a): ...
    def log_bar(self, b, c): ...


class MultiLogger:
    def __init__(self, loggers: list[Logger]):
        self.loggers = loggers

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if callable(getattr(Logger, name, None)):
            return self._make_proxy(name)
        raise AttributeError(name)

    def _make_proxy(self, name):
        def proxy(*args, **kwargs):
            for logger in self.loggers:
                getattr(logger, name)(*args, **kwargs)
        return proxy


# PyCharm (rightfully) complains about the following:
#     "Expected type 'Logger', got 'MultiLogger' instead"
# With mypy it works though.
logger: Logger = MultiLogger([LoggerA(), LoggerB()])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no real code repetition in a DRY sense. It's just similar code, which might be repetitive to write.

The design of `MultiLogger` is in line with the other loggers. Someone who understood `LoggerA` or B, will understand the multilogger right away. I don't think there is a reason to change it.

**Nevertheless, some ideas for alternatives**:
This just saves one line per method (at least the line which is the most repetitive one):

```
def execute_all(self, func):
    for logger in self.loggers:
        func(logger)

def log_foo(self, a):
    self.execute_all(lambda l: l.log_foo(a))
```

A more interesting alternative would be chaining of loggers. This would make a dedicated `MultiLogger` class unnecessary:

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, next=None):
        self.next = next

class LoggerA(Logger):
    def log_foo(self, a):
        print(a)
        if self.next:
            self.next.log_foo(a)

# usage e.g.:
logger = LoggerA(LoggerB())
```